# I am unable to get a month from this date format mm/yyyy using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am unable to get a month from this date format **mm/yyyy** please help me how can I get a month from input bootstrap date picker thanks.

I am getting a date in this formate **01/2021**

```js
$(".monthDatePicker").datepicker({
  format: "mm/yyyy",
  viewMode: "months",
  minViewMode: "months"
});


// for monthly
$('#from_date').on('change', function() {
  // var daily_monthly ="{{$propertyAds->monthly_date}}"

  var from_date = $("#from_date").val(); // 01/2021

  console.log(from_date)
  var d = new Date(from_date);
  var n = d.getMonth();
  console.log(n);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your update working code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>

<input id="from_date" class="monthDatePicker">
<script>
$(".monthDatePicker").datepicker({
  format: "mm/yyyy",
  viewMode: "months",
  minViewMode: "months"
});


// for monthly
$('#from_date').on('change', function() {
  // var daily_monthly ="{{$propertyAds->monthly_date}}"
   var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
            day  = date.getDate(),  
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
            year =  date.getFullYear();
        alert(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```